# Volume rocker only works AFTER system resume from sleep

Tags: suspend, volume-control, keys, resume

I am using Ubuntu 16.04.1 on a Dell XPS 12 ultrabook.  The volume rocker (at the side of the laptop) only works after the system has been resumed after entering sleep mode.  The FN+Volume keys always work.  I have also tried Ubuntu 16.10 and the problem still persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by blacklisting the intel_vbtn kernel module (Intel Virtual Button), by adding `blacklist intel_vbtn` to `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`, and then running `sudo update-initramfs -u`.